# UIPopoverController does not dismiss when clicking on the NavigationBar and NavigationBar items

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

i am new in ios .I have a navigation bar that contains multiple buttons, including a back button, sort ,filter,settings button and a button that opens a popover . `UIPopoverController` not dismissed when opened from `navigationItem` inside `UINavigationController`.

When i click filter navigation item `popoverView` controller working fine but the problem is if i click other navigation items like back,sort,setting not dismissing.when i tap or touch on  navigation bar popover not dismissing how to rectify this problem?

viewController.h

```
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
```

viewController.m

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] target:self action:@selector(onBack)];

UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

UIButton *btnMainLogo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btnMainLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dina_new_logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnMainLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 36);
[btnMainLogo addTarget:self action:@selector(onHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
item.titleView = btnMainLogo;

item.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;

//RIGHT MENU
NSMutableArray *arrRightBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIButton *btnSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnSetting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSetting.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btnSetting.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
[btnSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(onSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSetting];

UIButton *btnShare = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnShare.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
btnShare.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
[btnShare addTarget:self action:@selector(onShare:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnShare];

UIBarButtonItem *edit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(onEditIssue:)];
UIBarButtonItem *sortByDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"Sort"
                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(onSortByDate:)];
UIBarButtonItem *FilterByIssue = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"Filter"
                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(onFilterByIssue:)];



NSArray *arrBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:barButtonItem,barButtonItem1,edit,sortByDate,FilterByIssue, nil];
[arrRightBarItems addObjectsFromArray:arrBtns];
[item setRightBarButtonItems:arrRightBarItems];
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing the popover in the callbacks for each bar button item. For instance:

```
-(void)onEditIssue:(id)sender
{
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible])
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: i already done,but if i touch navigation bar not dismiss not a navigation item

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136792/uipopovercontroller-does-not-dismiss-when-clicking-on-the-navigationbar) question's accepted answer worked for me. Set the popover controller's `passthroughViews` to nil just after presenting it.