# UIPopoverPresentationController doesn't disable tap gesture on title view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have view controller with navigation bar containing title view which handles tap gesture. Also there is a `rightBarButtonItem` which shows `UIAlertController` on iPad as popover. Example code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    titleLabel.text = @"Popover test";
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;
    titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(titleLabelPress)]];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                           target:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(showPopover)];
}

- (void)showPopover {
    UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                        message:nil
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    controller.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

    [controller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"One" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [controller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Two" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)titleLabelPress {
    BOOL isYellow = [((UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView).backgroundColor isEqual:UIColor.yellowColor];
    ((UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView).backgroundColor = isYellow ? UIColor.greenColor : UIColor.yellowColor;
}
```

The problem is when popover is presenting I still able to tap on title label and popover won't dismiss. Also if I tap on status bar popover won't dismiss. What could be the reason of that problems?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an answer at:

[UIPopoverController does not dismiss when clicking on the NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136792/uipopovercontroller-does-not-dismiss-when-clicking-on-the-navigationbar)

> UIPopoverController seems to add the navigation bar to its
>   passthroughViews array when it is presented.

The solution is to do:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
    controller.popoverPresentationController.passthroughViews = nil;
}];
```

Comment: Yep, it was. Did some additional research and it seems that from iOS11 it nil by default. Thanks.